# spring boot resource on separate port

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application where I want to segment the API into different ports.
There should be an admin API exposed on one port and and external one on a different port.

This I can achieve by starting multiple spring applications from one java process. But to complicate things there should be an additional endpoint for monitoring which of course needs the context of the both applications(I want to leverage spring actuator).

So is it possible to segment a spring boot API in this way, where a certain set of controllers are on one port and another set on another port?

Comment: this looks like what you are asking: https://tech.asimio.net/2016/12/15/Configuring-Tomcat-to-Listen-on-Multiple-ports-using-Spring-Boot.html

Comment: hmm, yeah seems like it. although it looks like that won't work on later versions of spring and I prefer starting out on a later version. `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory` is no longer present in spring boot 2.1.7

Comment: I had a similar issue in past, and what I ended up is redirect using apache configs. Not a solution to your problem, but a possible alternative.